# Oracle pl sql dynamic using clause

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, cursor, using

I have a question about "dynamic using clause" in execute immediate statement. I need to set dynamically the "execute immediate statement" and the using clause as well. I don't know the table structure, but I know only the name of the table, and I need to do an operation update on it.

So I wrote a function (through user_tab_columns and user user_constraints tables) to set a variable with the update statement and the bind_variable but now I need to set the using clause with the list of variable.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
  rec1  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)           NULL,
  rec2       DATE                          NULL,
  rec3 number(9) not null
);

 declare
 TYPE cur_type IS REF CURSOR;
 cur cur_type;
 table_list table1%ROWTYPE;
 sqlstring varchar2(400);

 begin
 OPEN cur FOR sqlstring;
 LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO table_list;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    sqlstring:=function1('table1');
    -- that returns sqlstring:='update table1 set rec1=:1 , rec2=:2 , rec3=:3 where rec_id=:c4';

    execute immediate sqlstring using table_list.rec1, table_list.rec2, table_list.rec3, table_list.rec_id;
END LOOP;
close cur;
end;
```

I need to implement dynamically the list of variables of the cursor table_list.

"execute immediate sqlstring using table_list.rec1, table_list.rec2, table_list.rec3, table_list.rec_id"

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: How does function `function1` look like. I think instead of returning a plain statement you must work with `DBMS_SQL` package already there.

Comment: What is actually wrong with what you have shown - do you get an error, or wrong results?

Comment: where are you deriving ,  " table_list.rec_id " from ? It is not part of your table strucutre

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your replies.

The problem is that I'm assuming I don't know the table's structure and so the list of variables of the cursor table_list table1%ROWTYPE.
So I can't explicit table_list.rec1, table_list.rec2 ... in the using clause.

If I use only table_list as variable

```
begin
OPEN cur FOR sqlstring;
LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO table_list;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    sqlstring:=function1('table1');
execute immediate sqlstring using table_list;
END LOOP;
close cur;
```

I got the error:" 00457 Expressions have to be of SQL types"

http://psoug.org/oraerror/PLS-00457.htm

Error Cause:
An expression of wrong type is in USING or dynamic RETURNING clause. In USING or dynamic RETURNING clause, an expression cannot be of non-SQL types such as BOOLEAN, INDEX TABLE, and record.

I need a way to retrive not only the values but also the list of variables of the cursor table_list first.
But maybe it's impossible and I have to find a work around.

If I will find something interesting I will post.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your execute immediate to full use of dbms_sql.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i996891

And usefull for you will be bind_array function from this package.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic PL/SQL, unless you can re-factor the original statement and just plug the values into it.

```
declare
    v_string constant varchar2(32767) := 'update test1 set a = :1, b = :2';
    v_using_string varchar2(32767);
begin
    --Create dynamic using string.
    --For example, let's say you want to pass in the values "1" for each NUMBER column.
    select listagg(1, ',') within group (order by null)
    into v_using_string
    from user_tab_columns
    where table_name = 'TEST1'
        and data_type = 'NUMBER';

    --Execute the original dynamic SQL, adding the USING string.
    execute immediate '
        begin
            execute immediate '''||v_string||''' using '||v_using_string||';
        end;
    ';
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `DBMS_SQL` package:

1. open a cursor using `dbms_sql.open_cursor`
2. parse the statement using `dbms_sql.parse`
3. bind variables in a loop using `dbms_sql.bind_variable`
4. execute the statement using `dbms_sql.execute`
5. and finally close the cursor using `dbms_sql.close_cursor`

Or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` of anonymous PL/SQL block, which performs a dynamically created `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` (this approach is not suitable for returning data). See Answer of @JonHeller.